# How to Skip Retake/Use Photo option after capturing image by camera in IOS 7

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

Here I am developing an app using IOS 7 in which camera used to capture the image. but after capturing image it displaying Retake/Use Photo options. i want that after capturing image it directly go to next screen without showing default Retake?use Photo Options.I google out this Issue but I don't get proper solution. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code snippet that i am using in my project

[image]

```
-(void)StartCamera

{

if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])

{  

  UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"           message:@"Device has no camera" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [myAlertView show];
}
else
{ 
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The stock `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` provided by iOS has both these buttons.

One way to achieve what you want is to continue to use `UIImagePickerViewController` and set `showsCameraControls` to `NO`. Then, provide your own user interface using `cameraOverlayView` for your custom overlay view.

```
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;

self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;
```

Another way is to use `AVFoundation` to create your own camera view.

Comment: Cool! Also, check out this example from Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Here's the code with AVFoundation https://github.com/lteu/demo_AVFoundation . Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
```

For both Camera as well as gallery.

If you're using any third party library for editing it will directly guide you to that library or dismiss the picker controller without giving preview.

Comment: allowEditing set to NO (false) for camera does not do this for me. I still get the retake/Use Photo controls

Comment: @ChrisPrince I made some changes in my answer that helps you to resolve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is not correct. Setting the options as shown has no effect on the use/retake UI that iOS presents. That's not what the .allowsEditing option does.